# A java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

A java.lang.NullPointerException occurs when a Java application or Java applet has been badly coded. Typically, the Java program (and consequently, the programmer) attempted to access the reference or handle to a Java object that did not exist

I have  gone round in circles reading . I have made two minimal files  - Two.java will compile.

```
 public class Two {
   public static int width;
   public static int height;

   public static void main(String[] args) {
     int width = 320;
     int height = 100;  
     System.out.println(width + "," + height);
   }
 }
```

One.java in eclipse will print the string intwo to console. My question is if
it will print, Why is it null?
I am trying to  convert  the string to int so I can do  math with it. In real life there is a lot more than two  numbers arriving in.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class One {
  public static int width;
  public static int height;

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar Two.jar");
    BufferedReader is;
    String intwo;
    is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

    while ((intwo = is.readLine()) != null)
      System.out.println(intwo); // Prints to console

    String[] items = (intwo).split(","); //java.langNullPointerException
    int[] results = new int[items.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      results[i] = Integer.parseInt(items[i]);
    }
    System.out.println(results[1]);
  }
}
```

Comment: please improve the format of your code the next time.

Comment: Can you add stack trace of the exception?

Comment: Post the whole stack trace. Always post the whole stack trace.

Comment: Maroun Maroun, Egor and Sethiel all gave you the correct answer. However, you might want to try stepping through your code line by line in the debugger before posting this sort of question to Stack Overflow. It should be easy to see the behavior they described

Answer (score 2):

```
while ((intwo = is.readLine()) != null)
  System.out.println(intwo); // Prints to console

//Here intwo is guaranteed to be null!!!!
String[] items = (intwo).split(",");
```

By the way, it is a bad practice to write `if/while` statements without curly braces. You should really avoid it.

Comment: +1 - `intwo` guaranteed to be `null` otherwise the loop wouldn't exit.

Comment: Maroun Maroun, Egor and Sethiel all gave you the correct answer. However, you might want to try stepping through your code line by line in the debugger before posting this sort of question to Stack Overflow. It should be easy to see the behavior they described.

Comment: I think you did not post at the right place.

Answer (score 1):

Here's your `while` clause:

```
while ((intwo = is.readLine()) != null)
  System.out.println(intwo); // Prints to console
```

It exists when `intwo` is `null`, right? So it's obvious that on the next line `intwo` will be `null`
and will cause a `NullPointerException`:

```
String[] items = (intwo).split(","); //java.langNullPointerException
```

Answer (score 1):

See your code:

`while ((intwo = is.readLine()) != null)`

When do you exit the `while` loop? When `intwo` is `null`!

So when you exit the loop, you're doing `null.split(",");` which of course causes NPE.

Put parenthesis around the `while` loop and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
while ((intwo = is.readLine()) != null)
    System.out.println(intwo); // Prints to console
String[] items = (intwo).split(","); //java.langNullPointerException
```

Of course you get NullPointerException. You basically iterate until intwo is null (so you *ensure* intwo is null) and then you call a method on that null reference.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
 while ((intwo = is.readLine()) != null)
 System.out.println(intwo); // Prints to console
 String[] items = (intwo).split(",");
```

is the same as this:

```
while ((intwo = is.readLine()) != null){
    System.out.println(intwo); // Prints to console
}

String[] items = (intwo).split(",");
```

It gets pretty obvious why you get a NullPointerException